# Proof for definition of the direct sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, direct-sum

I don't get how this definition can describe direct sum of subspaces.
What is (detailed/noob) explanation for this definition?
What is proof for it?

For subspaces $$(P_1, . . . , P_k),$$ we define direct sum  if  $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i \neq 0,$$
when  $$x_i \in P_i$$ for
$$i = {1 \ldots k}, $$ if there is $$ i_0 \in {1, . . . , k}, $$ that $$x_{i_0} \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

It means that the sum of the spaces is direct if the following property is satisfied:

> For all $\;(x_1,\dots,x_k)\;$ such that $\;x_1\in P_1,\dots,\, x_k\in P_k$, if an $x_i$ is not $0$, then $\; x_1+\dots+x_k\ne0$.
>
> Taking the contrapositive, it means that $\;\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$ is $0$ if and only if *each* $x_i$ is $0$.

Comment: Ok. I heard for contrapositive, and i understand to some degree. Can you put proof for contrapositive definition? .... Also  I asked for this definition, as it is, not for contrapositive, so please  if you have some proof or simply example/explanation for it, post.

Comment: The contrapositive of an implication $\;A\implies B$ is tjust the reverse implication on the negations: $\;\neg B \implies \neg A$. These implications are logically equivalent. For instance, said in plain language: any multiple of $6$ is even (1st implication). It is the  same to say that no odd number can be a multiple of $6$ (contrapositive of the 1st implication).